# How to allow of contents behind the soft keyboard in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-softkeyboard

I have a `scrollview` that has `android:fillViewport="true"` so that it fills the screen when there is no keyboard.  I want to add functionality so that the scrollview doesn't change when a keyboard pops up, but rather allows you to scroll the contents up from BEHIND the keyboard.
  Is this possible?  I don't want the keyboard to pop up and everything gets squished together.  Does anyone have a solution to this?

Comment: Not sure but try android:configChanges="keyboardHidden" in the manifest and report back.

Comment: That is the standard UI pattern and assumed behavior for Android users. So I suggest you should not change this behavior and adjust your views differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting height and width of scroll view to "match_parent" is the trick here.

Check below layout, it will help you.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="38dp" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/relative_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="13dp"
            android:paddingRight="8dp" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_fullname"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:maxLength="30"
                android:maxWidth="208dp"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textSize="13sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_email"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:maxLength="30"
                android:maxWidth="208dp"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:textSize="13sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_phone"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="400dp"
                android:digits="1234567890"
                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                android:inputType="phone"
                android:maxLength="12"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textSize="13sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_fax"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:digits="1234567890"
                android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                android:inputType="phone"
                android:maxLength="12"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textSize="13sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
                android:text="Botttom Text" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Kindly if you explain little more, it is great help from you, i have done this but all in vain.